# Finding the Transformation in Linear Combination Form

Tags: vectors, linear-transformations

Let **v** and **w** be (fixed, but unknown) vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, which are not scalar multiples of each others.
Suppose that $T$: $\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a linear transformation such that
$$T(-2v-3w) = -2v-3w \space \space \space and \space \space \space T(v+w) = -2v+3w$$

The question is: *What is $T$(**v**) in terms of **v** and **w**? (Expressed as a linear combination of v and w)*

If I were to express **v** as a linear combination of $-2v-3w$ and $v+w$, I get $$v=c_1(-2v-3w)+c_2(v+w)$$
Not sure how to go on about from here and calculate for $T(v)$. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two vectors which are not scalar multiples of each other are  linearly independent. Hence, $$v=c_1(-2v-3w)+c_2(v+w)$$ yields $$(1+2c_1)v+(3c_1-c_2)w=0$$ and  so $1+2c_1=0=3c_1-c_2$. This gives $c_1=-\frac  1 2$ and $c_2=-\frac 3  2$. Now use linearity to calculate $Tv$.